# What kind of machine is used to print designs on plastics

Tags: print-design, design-process

What kind of machine or process is used to print designs on hard plastics?

For example: Mouse, Chargers, Speakers etc.

Comment: Hi Nik, welcome to the site. It'd be helpful if you could [edit] your post to include example images of what you have in mind as there are a few options here. Using complete sentences in your post is also appreciated

Comment: A screenprinting machine could do that.

Answer (score 1):

They're usually done on a large dye sublimation printer. Since those machines are very expensive, I would suggest outsourcing it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 0):

- If the plastic pice is already extruded, a verey interesting (and cool) option is hydrographics.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrographics_%28printing%29

But obviously it is before you asamble it.

- For flat surcaces (The side of a speaker for example) a simple screen print is a good option. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_printing

You can aso print on round shapes like cylinders with this method.

- In some other cases, depending on the complexity of the design a decal printed on a transparent material could be the best opiton.